# After updating to 4.8 permalinks will not work (all 404)

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, server, nginx

I honestly did expect to get here...
I tried every tool in the book...
`Save changes` on the `permalinks` page...
I installed `debug this` to see what going on with the `query`...
I repeated other operations and changes to configurations but of no avail.
I've spent hours reading on `.htaccess` params as well as `nginx` server block configurations...nothing worx.
My `menu` keeps on giving `404` unless I set `permalinks` to `plain`.
I am on `linode VPS`, `ubuntu 14.04` + `LEMP` stack
Here are my `.htaccess` & my site's configs...

**.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

# Leverage Browser Caching Ninja -- Starts here
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On 
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month" 
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year" 
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month" 
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month" 
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month" 
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month" 
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month" 
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year" 
</IfModule> 
# Leverage Browser Caching Ninja -- Ends here


# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

**nginx server block**

```
server {
        server_name www.xxx.com xxx.com;
        root /home/alma/xxx.com;
        index index.php;
        include global/restrictions.conf;
        include global/wordpress_xxx.conf;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/xxx_error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/xxx_access.log;
}
```

**global/wordpress_xxx.conf**

```
# http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule
location / {
    #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}

# Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

# Directives to send expires headers and turn off 404 error logging.
location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
       access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
}

# Pass all .php files onto a php-fpm/php-fcgi server.
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
#   fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 16M \n post_max_size=18M";
    client_max_body_size 68M;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ ^/(wp-admin|wp-login\.php) {
        auth_basic "Welcome - Admin Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
}

location = /wp-login.php {
    deny all;

    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 16M \n post_max_size=18M";
    client_max_body_size 68M;
}
```

**global/restrictions.conf**

```
# Global restrictions configuration file.
location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
}

location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
}
```

These all worked prior to the last `update`...
Has anyone encountered such an issue?
Does anyone know how to resolve this?
Is there something in my configuration that might be causing the issue after the `update` to 4.8?
Thanx

P.s. the error logs are not showing anything in particular...

Comment: Try removing the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrapper - do you get an error? You appear to employing a "WordPress" front controller in both the Nginx config file _and_ `.htaccess`? Why both? Your `.htaccess` file contains an exception for `403.shtml` - but this isn't referenced in the config files shown here?

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into that trouble before with some of my sites when I transferred them to another server.

Here's what I did. edit your `apache2.conf` at `/etc/apache2/` folder.

Run the following command:

```
nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Scroll down and look for this section with a comment:

```
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
```

Make sure that this is the one in there:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride all
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

For short, grant it. For your permalinks not to fail.

-Dave

Answer (score 0):

You might try `flush_rewrite_rules( $hard );`
Be sure to remove the function aftewards though.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules